# Python class definition based on a condition

Tags: python, class

I found a similar class definition as below in a Python code base. It seems there is no similar examples in the official documents. Very hard to find similar thing by Google and searching in the forum. May anyone help me to understand the principle in Python behind this?

```
class a: pass
class b: pass
condition = True
class c(a if condition == True else b): pass
```

Comment: In the syntax of the more traditional ternary operator, the statement inside the parenthesis is equivalent to `condition ? a : b`.

Comment: More pythonic to use `if condition else b` (`== True` is superfluous)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a if condition == True else b` is a ternary expression.

It means use `a` as base class if `condition` equals `True` else use `b`.

As `condition == True` is `True` so it uses `a`:

```
>>> class c(a if condition == True else b): pass
>>> c.__bases__
(<class __main__.a at 0xb615444c>,)
```

Examples:

```
>>> print 'foo' if 0>1 else 'bar'
bar
>>> print 'foo' if 1>0 else 'bar'
foo
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

> The expression `x if C else y` first evaluates the condition, `C` (not
>   `x`); if `C` is true, `x` is evaluated and its value is returned;
>   otherwise, `y` is evaluated and its value is returned.

Comment: Wow, how can I didn't find this. Thanks, Ashwini!